# Prometheus Exporter: Handling Stale Measurements

Tags: prometheus

I'm writing my first Prometheus Exporter.
I am using a GaugeVec to store metrics from similar components differentiated by 3 different labels, such as IP, slot number, ports, etc.

Let's say one of the components at a specific IP stops responding, what would be the best way to remove this metric? I could possibly remove it by iterating through all the possible lables, but it feels quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing exporters you should not be using the usual direct instrumentation APIs, amongst other reasons it has this problem.

Instead as you are using Go you should use MustNewConstMetric to create samples only for a single scrape.